# Is that query safe and written fine?

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

I have a query like that, it is created to replace certain phrase in a description inside lot of products in prestashop but actually should work with any database.

I'm using MySQL workbench 8.0 and when trying to execute that it prompts that safe mode is enabled and it is to prevent updating multiple rows without proper use of where clause, it works okay if i use that query on only one record (with modified where) .

My question is, is it okay to turn off safe mode?

I know that this query will work okay and it is intended to update many rows with only that specific where clause (like "%phrase%" because from select i can tell results are fine.

Maybe i'm missing something important?

```
update ps_product_lang 
    set ps_product_lang.description = REPLACE( ps_product_lang.description, 
'phrase to replace', 'phrase replaced' )
where ps_product_lang.description like '%searched phrase%';
```

Or is there any other good option to replace specific phrase in 1400 products?
Prestashop 1.7.6.1

Comment: You are only going to do this ONCE surely, so if it works just do it. 1400 products is a fairly trivial number of rows

Comment: `I know that this query will work okay and it is intended to update many rows with only that specific where clause` sure, but if you - at a stressful day - for some reason forgot an important `WHERE` for a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` which would mess up your data,  you will be happy about the safe mode ;).

Comment: This is an *internal* request, you won't allow *external* users to run it. So no need to worry about safety. Safety is an issue if you allow users to provide data to be entered into the data base e.g. via a web interface – you need to protect yourself against e.g. SQL injections then; assume a user provided a seached phrase like `'; delete from someImportantTable; select * from wherever where someText = '` – what would happen if you just pasted in unchanged???

Comment: If you want to *test* the query first to see if it indeed produces the desired results then you might start a transaction separately before, run it, retrieve the data, check it and then on success commit, on errors rollback ;)

Comment: Okay, thank You guys for fast answers :) . Yeah it will be one time thing and only I have access to that. Also about accidental delete or update, i will enable that after doing that thing because before i never had to worry about that safe mode so good it is there watching 'if something' :D.